# Read a number, display it on the screen using a simple method (C++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the `n` number using a method. When I try to build it with `F7`, the program returns an error:

> Error  1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'n' used.

Could you please help me create a method to read a number and display it on the screen?

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void read_number(int n){
    do {
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 3 || n > 50);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    read_number(n);
    cout << "Number: " << n << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the value of `main`'s variable `n` to the function.
The variable is not modified by the function, only the function's parameter is.

The simplest way is to return a value from the function:

```
int read_number(){
    int x = 0;
    do {
        cin >> x;
    } while (x < 3 || x > 50);
    return x;
}

int main(){
    int n = read_number();
    cout << "Number: " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or, if you definitely want to modify `main`'s variable, pass a reference to it:

```
void read_number(int& x){
    do {
        cin >> x;
    } while (x < 3 || x > 50);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    read_number(n);
    cout << "Number: " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void read_number(int n) {
> ```

In this function `n` is passed **by value**, which means that any modification that you made on `n` inside the function's body is *not* reflected outside the function.

If you want to return the read number to the caller, either return it from the function, making it:

```
int read_number()
```

or pass pass `n` by non-const **reference**:

```
void read_number(int& n);
```

I'd prefer the former.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is pass by value unless you specify otherwise.

With that in mind, note that a copy is passed to `readNumber`; it doesn't mutate its argument.

Change the helper to:

```
void read_number(){
    int n;
    do {
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 3 || n > 50);
    return n;
```

}

Note we're mutating the local variable instead, then returning it.

Then, change your main to deal with the change:

```
int main(){
    int n = read_number();
    cout << "Number: " << n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As @Mr.C64 points out, you can pass by reference instead, and then you can mutate the parameter, but that should be avoided unless it's absolutely necessary. It's much harder to read code containing mutations like that.